# Написал новостной парсер на Python, не могу подключить БД mySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Написал парсер на Python, не могу подключить БД mySQL. Необходимо чтобы, результат парсера  забивал в базу, заголовок, ссылка, время.  Нужна помощь срочно.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time

url = "https://www.nur.kz/latest/"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
articles_cards = soup.find_all("a", class_="article-preview-category__content")

for article in articles_cards:
    article_title = article.find("h2", class_="article-preview-category__subhead").text.strip()
    #article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()
    article_url = f'{article.get("href")}'

    article_date_time = article.find("time").get("datetime")
    date_from_iso = datetime.fromisoformat(article_date_time)
    date_time = datetime.strftime(date_from_iso, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    article_date_timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())

    print(article_title,"|||", article_url, '|||', article_date_timestamp)
```

Comment: Вы, как минимум, задачу сформулируйте. У вас вопрос в заголовке - если вы не уверены, что надо подключать, то поясните тем, кто может помочь, почему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать и какие проблемы с подключением у вас возникли?

Comment: Вроде подключился к своей базе, но нужно чтобы результат каким то образом сохранялся.

Comment: Так а проблема-то какая? Как вы уже пытались сохранять и почему в вас не получилось?

Comment: Пытался сохранять, по итогу ничего не вышло, разные ошибки выдавало. Дело в том, что мне нужно чтобы, кто нибудь показал как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import time

url = "https://www.nur.kz/latest/"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
articles_cards = soup.find_all("a", class_="article-preview-category__content")

#news_dict = {}
for article in articles_cards:
    article_title = article.find("h2", class_="article-preview-category__subhead").text.strip()
    #article_desc = article.find("p").text.strip()
    article_url = f'{article.get("href")}'

    article_date_time = article.find("time").get("datetime")
    date_from_iso = datetime.fromisoformat(article_date_time)
    date_time = datetime.strftime(date_from_iso, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    article_date_timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())

    #print(article_title,"|||", article_url, '|||', article_date_timestamp)

    #Подключился к базе
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='',
                                 db='testdb123',
                                 charset='utf8',
                                 autocommit=True)
    print ("connect successful!!")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    url = 'https://www.nur.kz/latest/'
    array = get_data(get_html(url))

    sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO users (`article_title`, `article_url`, `article_date_timestamp`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
    cursor=mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula,(str(article_title)),str(article_url),str(article_date_timestamp))
    mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Так и не получилось(

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).